# How do I make background images only show on home page?

Tags: css

I added this background to body later to realize I wanted it only to appear on the front page. How do I do it?

```
background: url(/Imagenes/tipbusca.png) 10px 400px no-repeat,  url(/Imagenes/tippublica.png) 96% 200px no-repeat;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give a class to `body` for just the home page then target that class:

```
body.home {
    background: url(/Imagenes/tipbusca.png) 10px 400px no-repeat,  url(/Imagenes/tippublica.png) 96% 200px no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Do I add that class with PHP so that it only adds when it's front page? Or is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: @Liso22: If you're using PHP to serve your pages, yes you can use it to determine what's the home page, and add the class if so.

Comment: I already did it. It took me like ten seconds, I'm just starting with this. Thanks

Comment: Sorry to revive an old post but why would it be a class and not an id? Shouldn't it be an id since there's only one instance per page?

Comment: @arasmussen: Stylistic choice. If you prefer to use an ID, you can do so.